# How to install pip for a specific version of Python

Tags: python, pip

`pip install xyz` calls Python2.7 pip.

So, I try: `python2.6 -m pip install xyz`

and get: `/usr/bin/python2.6: No module named pip`

How do I install pip for my Python 2.6 so I can use the above command?

It's not installed, I tried pip2.6, and all the other recommended names on here.

Comment: A better question might be why you're stuck using an 11 year old interpreter. Upgrade!

Comment: Try building a virtual environment specifying python2.6 as the python interpreter, I like virtualenv, activate the environment and use pip from there

Comment: Notably Pip does not support Python 2.6 anymore, so any version you get will be an old one that may not support all features. See the [PyPA page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/) for details

Comment: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py -- I believe this will still work for 2.6, but 2.6 is a REALLY bad idea :)